# SwiftUI ScrollView() programmatically scroll

Tags: audio, swiftui, progress-bar, scrollview, avaudioplayer

I'm making an audio player for books.

[image]

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make ScrollView() autoscroll for 1pt each second. How can I use ScrollViewReader when there's one long bar to scroll, I don't have elements to hook up for?

Book Scroll view:

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders], content: {
            Section(header: caret) {
                
                // Book's progress bar
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(red: 0.17, green: 0.17, blue: 0.18))
                    .frame(width: playerEngine.bookPlaybackWidth, height: 40)
                // Caret - playback position
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                                               value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.x)
                    })
                
                    .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
                        // Updating offset and applying center to get caret offset
                        offset = $0+center
                    }
            }
        })
        // Trailing padding for whole lazy stack so caret and playback bounces off
            .padding([.trailing], center)
    }
    .frame(height: 96)
    .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
```

Comment: I had idea, have't tried yet using ScrollViewReader proxy render an empty object at playback time > scroll to It > destroy it > repeat. Going to try it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for editing! I'm close to solving it. I created an Invisible Rectangle and use it as .id() for Proxy in ScrollViewReader. And before it I have Rectangle() - current progress-bar that is = to player?.currentTime. It does work but a bit junky, so trying to polish then will publish it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution I came up with that is somewhat stable.

[image]

Code:

```
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    // Book's width
                    Path{ path in
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20))
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: playerEngine.bookPlaybackWidth, y: 20)) 
                    }
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle( lineWidth: 40, dash: [2]))
                    .foregroundColor(darkProgressBar)
                    .frame(width: playerEngine.bookPlaybackWidth, height: 40)
                    
                    // Caret - offset
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                                               value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.x)
                    })
                    .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
                        // Updating offset and applying center to get caret offset
                        offset = $0+center
                    }
                    
                    // progress
                    Path{ path in
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20))
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: playerEngine.currentProgress ?? 0, y: 20))
                    }
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle( lineWidth: 40, dash: [2]))
                    .foregroundColor(lightDark)
                    .frame(width: playerEngine.currentProgress ?? 0, height: 40)
                    .id(currentProgress)
                }
                .onChange(of: playerEngine.currentProgress) { _ in
                    autoScroll(proxy: proxy)
                }
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], center)
            }
}
```

I use ScrollViewReader's proxy and autoScroll(proxy:proxy) is basically
`proxy.scrollTo(currentProgress, anchor: .trailing)`  To .id(currentProgress) at my progress bar that is updates every second.

Here's [docs on hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-scroll-view-move-to-a-location-using-scrollviewreader)

**BUT!** There's a problem with this solution, scrollTo - fails quickly if you're trying to use it more often than once / second. And I don't know how to avoid it. If you know something please share, much appreciated!

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, but one could probably put a guard as a kind of timekeeper to insulate against the "more than a second" fail. In other words - either a check or a boolean unset/set each second; as long as it's set, no more interaction will be accepted (so no fail), a new second - it resets, sets any progress, and then is clamped again until another second has passed.

Comment: Did you solve this problem somehow? I am currently facing similar issues

Comment: @JasonKrowl nothing better than in the answer unfortunately. And that one is not super stable as well :( If you find something also please drop here!